# multiline text causing div container to be pushed down

Tags: css

I have a button component which is basically a button and a text beneath this button. both share the same container.
when the text (beneath the button, not inside it), is multiline, the button is pushed down, causing weird alignment issue

I tried to separate the 'text' css class outside to another separate div, it did not work. I also tried to give the parent 'vertical-align: top' (because I read somewhere that the problem might be caused due to the text push the parent's vertical-align: baseline down. It did not make any difference and didn't fix my issue

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    cursor: pointer;
    .icon {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
    }
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 13px; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}

relevant jsx (react):
<div className='container'>
  <div>
    <button className='button' style={buttonColors}>
    <div className='icon'/>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div className='text'> {text} </div>
  </div>
    );
```

the expected results: whenever there is multiline text, the text will continue down, not pushing the buttom down.

Comment: You have shared the incomplete CSS Code. Please re-post.

Comment: sorry. updated css

Answer (score 0):

adding vertical-align:top to button-container does solve the problem. My mistake was to put it another place.
in this way, the multiline text is not causing the parent 'baseline' which comes from vertical align: baseline which is the default, to be pushed down